# Ruby on Rails, what's the correct way to relate two instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to learning Rails 3 and working through a Q&A app tutorial. I'm just wondering why I can't do this (I get an error) in relating a particular answer to a question. It works for the current user...

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :auth, only: [:create]

def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    **@answer = Answer.new(params[:answer])
    @answer.question = @question
    @answer.user = current_user**
    if @answer.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your answer has been posted!'
        redirect_to @question
    else
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        render 'questions/show'
    end
end
end
```

The tutorial says that this is the correct way:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :auth, only: [:create]

def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    **@answer = @question.answers.build(params[:answer])**
    @answer.user = current_user
    if @answer.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your answer has been posted!'
        redirect_to @question
    else
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        render 'questions/show'
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following

```
@answer = @question.answers.build(params[:answer)
```

Is the same as doing this

```
@answer = Answer.new(params[:answer])
@answer.question_id = @question.id
```

Doing a `build` adds the relation attributes to the new answer, in this case `question_id`

As for the error, can you provide the type of error you receive?

Comment: K, i managed to get it working. I'm not sure what went wrong. Thanks.